# Having problems with file_copy in Drupal 7

Tags: 7, files, debugging

In my particular situation I am trying to use Drupal's API to import a bunch of files from my computer into a local Drupal installation.  Seems like a smart idea.  So I have the following function:

```
  function create_picture_file($filepath, $public_place) {
    global $pic_basepath;
    $filepath = "$pic_basepath/$filepath";
    $file = new stdClass();
    $file->filename = basename($filepath);
    $file->filepath = $filepath;
    $file->filemime = file_get_mimetype($filepath);
    $file->filesize = filesize($filepath);
    $file->uid = 1;
    $file->status = FILE_STATUS_PERMANENT;
    $file->uri = $filepath;
    $file->display = 1;
    $file->description = '';
    print_r($file);
    $file = file_copy($file,"public://$public_place",FILE_EXISTS_REPLACE);
    print_r($file);
    return $file;
  }
```

You'll notice the two `print_r` statements towards the bottom.  The first one prints the following:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [filename] => Arctic_HE0302_Central_bathy.jpg
    [filepath] => /home/lpeabody/unclos_data/pics/Arctic_HE0302_Central_bathy.jpg
    [filemime] => image/jpeg
    [filesize] => 516130
    [uid] => 1
    [status] => 1
    [uri] => /home/lpeabody/unclos_data/pics/Arctic_HE0302_Central_bathy.jpg
    [display] => 1
    [description] => 
)
```

Which looks good.  The second one, however, print's absolutely nothing.  Any pointers or tips as to what I'm doing wrong maybe?

**UPDATE**
So the public file directory to which this image is being saved in is `region_images`.  When this directory exists, nothing get's printed by the second `print_r` statement.  When I remove the directory and all of it's associated style directories, the second `print_r` statement prints.  However, it prints the following:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [filename] => region_images
    [filepath] => /home/lpeabody/unclos_data/pics/Arctic_HE0302_Central_bathy.jpg
    [filemime] => image/jpeg
    [filesize] => 516130
    [uid] => 1
    [status] => 1
    [uri] => public://region_images
    [display] => 1
    [description] => 
    [fid] => 2595
    [timestamp] => 1331828075
)
```

Which is wrong, as `[filename]` should be `Arctic_HE0302_Central_bathy.jpg`.  Hopefully this can help shed some light on the situation.

Comment: It might be a simple folder permissions problem...when you manually create the `region_images` folder have you made sure the web server user has write permissions to it?

Comment: Ah, I did not specify the origin of the process. This is a custom PHP script I wrote and I bootstrap the Drupal environment from it.  I'm using it as a way to learn the API.  The permission weren't an issue as I was running the process and I have write permissions on the entire site installation.  I solved the problem by using Oswald's solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `"public://$public_place/$file->filename"` as `$destination` parameter for `file_copy()`.

Comment: Very, very strange.  It makes sense, but I've done similar file copies in the past successfully but without specifying the filename in the uri wrapper.  I wonder if it's because of the way Drupal handles images (in that multiple styles of images can exist in a multitude of different directories).